# How to activate the IntelliSense / Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

Is there any option to activate and deactivate this "help bar" ( IntelliSense ) ?

[image: Image captured in the main source]

It only works in the "main source". When I make a class (for example) it , somehow , deactivates. Is there any reason? I can deactivate and activate it for every single "window / source" ?

Comment: Just curious, but why don't you want IntelliSense?

Comment: Does your code compile? Do other IntelliSense features work properly? Autocompletion is supposed to work everywhere, however in VS2017 IntelliSense is unstable as never before.

Comment: Yes my code does compile. Well I suppose yes. I heard that IntelliSense is unstavle on this version. But VS2017 has a lot of new features  which makes my life easier.

Comment: If IntelliSense works in the main source i don't know why shouldn't it work for classes too. I guess I've acidentally disabled something when I tried to link a library. A miss click... I searched this but I can't find any answer.

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: EDIT : I *DON'T* know how but i somehow solved it. Just don't ask me how. I was just clicking on a few buttons and i checked if something happened and...yes. Just "playing" in the text editor options. I checked and uncheched them and... it worked :)) !